# IP address mapping between VLANs

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan

I am looking for a specific networking feature or set of features that was used on another project that I previously worked on. (I don't know my POC for that project otherwise I would ask them.)

In the previous project we had one switch with a dozen or so computers plugged into it. We had at least 3 VLANs configured on the switch. I managed all the devices on one of the VLANs. I was given a block of static IPs. Some of the IP address were mapped to another device that was on a different VLAN. And that device existed on it's own VLAN with a different IP.

I used that IP local to my VLAN to communicate with another computer on a different VLAN.

On a Cisco switch, what would that feature be called?

Comment: Switches don't let traffic flow between VLANs. You need to **_route_** traffic between VLANs. You either need a stand-alone router, or you need a layer-3 switch (has some routing built in).

Comment: I believe you're talking about Network Address Translation (NAT)

Comment: ip helper-address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic between VLAN ALWAYS must be routed - it's called **InterVlan Routing**.
InterVlan Routing can be achieved by using a Router, or a Layer 3 Switch.

For example, here are manuals by cisco with diagrams, all easy and graphically:

1. here is manual about configuring InterVLAN Routing on a Catalyst Switch Using an External Router:
   http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/14976-50.html
2. here is manual how to configure InterVLAN Routing on L3 switch Cisco:
   http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/41860-howto-L3-intervlanrouting.html

Feel free to ask details.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

On a Cisco Layer 3 switch (also known as a multilayer switch), the term is inter-vlan routing. As Tolga pointed out, if you're talking about a router it's called Rotuer on a Stick.

Although two different terms are used, they do exactly the same thing but they're done on different devices (switches and routers) and are connected in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you need to search for is `Router on a Stick`

If you want to communicate between vlans you need a Router which is connected to switch with trunk port.